# How can I append the same value to a ragged list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of character vectors:

```r
stuff <- list(c("cocaine", "corine"),
              c("dexitac"),
              c("ecstasy"),
              vector(mode="character"),
              c("amphetamine", "amfetamine",  "raphetamine", "anetamin"))
```

I would like to append another element (the word "OTHER") to the end of each of the character vectors.  By hand it would look like this:

```r
stuffOTHER <- list(c("cocaine", "corine", "OTHER"),
              c("dexitac", "OTHER"),
              c("ecstasy", "OTHER"),
              c("OTHER"),
              c("amphetamine", "amfetamine",  "raphetamine", "anetamin", "OTHER"))
```

How can I append the same string to each of the elements of a ragged list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and concatenate (`c`) "OTHER" at the end

```
stuff2 <- lapply(stuff, c, "OTHER")
identical(stuff2, stuffOTHER)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or with `Map`

```
Map(c, stuff, "OTHER")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Oh so obvious now that I see it.